# Rubymine selection jumps when I right-click in project list. Driving me crazy

Tags: rubymine

Not sure if it's a bug or a config issue on my end. But at some point Rubymine was updated and now when I right-click on anything in the project file listing on the left, the right-click menu appears but it jumps so that the item highlighted is one above what I clicked on. It's driving me nuts. I've included a photo.

[image: rubymine right-click menu]

Anyone seen this behavior before? There are so many settings in Rubymine I've been poking around in them to try and find something. This is version 2016.2.5

Answer (score 1):

Doh! When I checked my version so I add it to my question I wondered if I had accidentally turned off update notifications. I checked and sure enough version 2017.1 was available. I installed it and the annoying jump is gone! Also the interface rendering is much improved, looking much smoother.

Comment: Funny thing is this has been bothering me but the day I checked for the update is the day they released an update. LOL That's why I hadn't been alerted to it yet.